# How to rename directories, create headers without using mv command for very large files

Tags: bash, unix, sunos

I'm new to UNIX. I have 5 text files each with 500M records and I want to rename all 5 of them without using mv command. The first line in each file are column names. I want to replace the first line(column names) in each text files with headers(the text I want) before renaming all 5 files.

I'm using the following scripts for renaming  and creating headers.

**System configuration:**
Operating system: SunOS
bash shell

**Renaming directories:**

```
mv $file1 $name1
```

note: I tried rename command and it's not working on mine.

**Replacing the first line with headers:**
removing the first line:

```
sed '1d' $name1 > tmpfile
mv tmpfile $name1
```

appending the text on the first line:

```
echo "text" | cat - $name1 > text.txt.tmp 
mv text.txt.tmp $name1
```

I'm not getting any errors on running this. The problem is it's taking a very long time to perform these actions.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: You have text files each with 500M records, or you have 500M text files in a directory that you want to rename ?

Comment: I have 5 text files each with 500M records and I want to rename all 5 of them without using mv command.

Comment: To add, before you move these files do you want to replace anything in these text files ? Do you still want to rename the directory these files are in ? Please update your question explaining this a bit more clearly.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The first line are column names. I want to replace the first line(column names) in each text files with headers(the text I want) before renaming the 5 files. I dont want to rename the directory. My bad!.

Comment: Edit and update your question with all these things you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Why "without using mv"? Note per https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, we expect **practical** problems. Thus, a "without using X" restriction should be grounded in some kind of specific, practical limitation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no efficient way to add a header to an existing file using standardized UNIX interfaces, in **any** programming language.

This is because the syscall interface used to ask the operating system to perform filesystem operations lets you *append* to a file, or *replace* existing bytes with new contents of the exact same length -- but there's no standardized interface that lets you *insert* new bytes either at the beginning or in the middle of the file.

Modern Linux, with a small number of very specific filesystems, has some nonstandard syscalls available will let you add new blocks -- typically 4KB at a time -- but (1) this doesn't work on SunOS, (2) isn't accessible directly from bash, and (3) doesn't work if your content to insert isn't an exact multiple of block size, and aligned on a block-sized boundary on your file.

Comment: Thank you Charles!